# How do I ask for the right vocabulary for searching?

Tags: discussion, search, asking-questions, terminology

I don't know the precise word to use for my question. It may not even exist.

Suppose I am making an anagram service, but I don't know the word "anagram".

I want to ask "What search terms are useful for discovering technologies used to mix up letters to make words?"

Is this question appropriate for StackOverflow? Somewhere else?

Obviously, "anagram" isn't my exact issue, but my full question will have xml and code that describes the nature of my issue.

Comment: My argument would be that you have you understand what it is you're programming before you can program it.

Comment: @Makoto Disagree. I could program the anagram operation quite well, without ever knowing the word 'anagram'. My knowledge of the word would be helpful, however, for naming and (frankly) copying existing code.

Comment: @cmonkey:  I suppose my argument was, "Giving me source code tells me little unless I dive into it.  Telling me what you're trying to accomplish tells me everything without ever seeing a line of source."

Comment: If your only hangup is actually figuring out a word that describes your idea, Jim's suggestion of using EL&U is better - something like that would not be a good question here on Stack Overflow. If you have an actual programming problem and are having trouble describing it with a single word, describe it the best you can and just slide in an "Also, is there an easier way to describe this problem?" at the end. Surely someone will add in a "Yes, that's called an anagram, and here's how to solve your problem."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several questions on [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com) along those lines. You might be able to ask there to figure out what search terms to use.

Comment: Searching there found me the term I was looking for, so I didn't need to ask a new question. BTW, I ended up at "Web Annotations" for my particular problem.